# How to enforce specific objects in a method param

Tags: c#, oop

So I have a public method, where I want people to use helper objects for the params. The method is actually expecting a string, but I want to enforce using a string specifically returned by a helper object..

This example here, the first param 'qt' will expect a string, but I don't want people to pass just any string, I want them to only be able to pass MyObject.Property (Which returns a specific string.)

```
public string Query(QueryType qt, string artist, string album, string song)
{
  // DoStuff 
}
```

QueryType will be an Abstract Class, and will have properties like "GetSimilar", "GetTags", etc. Here is an example of how I want it to be used:

```
var json = LastFM.Query(Album.GetSimilar, "Nirvana", "Nevermind");
```

So I'd like to avoid things like this:

```
var whatever = new Album().GetSimilar;
var json = Query(whatever, "dah","dah","dah");
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the driver (reason, value) of forcing the caller to call `Query()` in the specific way? Why bother?

Comment: More or less, I just want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "smart enums pattern" like this:

```
public sealed class Album
{
    public static readonly Album Similiar = new Album("Similiar");
    public static readonly Album Tags = new Album("Tags");


    public string Value { get; private set; }

    private Album(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

and then the users can only use your pre-defined `Album` values.

```
public string Query(Album album)
{
    //do something        
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! both of these answers work fine! I'd +1 you, but not enough rep yet. :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use an enum for this. An enum defines a set of values that you can use, and is limited to that set of values.

If you want the first argument to only be `Album.GetSimilar` or some other values, you can do this

```
public enum QueryTypeEnum {
    AlbumGetSimilar,
    AlbumGetSomeOtherStuff,
    SomeOtherStuff
}
```

And change the method to accept a `QueryTypeEnum`. In the method, you can `switch` the parameter and do your things accordingly.

You can also do this for other parameters as well:

```
public enum Artist {...}
public enum Album {...}
public enum Song {...}
```

And your method will look like this:

```
public string Query(QueryTypeEnum qt, Artist artist, Album album, Song, song) {}
```

If you think this is too much code, just throw an `ArgumentException` if the arguments are wrong.

```
if (!CheckArgumentValid(song)) {
    throw new ArgumentException("The song is invalid");
}
```

Comment: Thanks you both of these answers work fine! I'd +1 you, but not enough rep yet. :(